# Acessar sites e extrair conteudos para o excel via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, aplicação-web, vba

Olá, eu estou querendo aprender como mexer em sites e extrair valores imagens, ou inserir senhas e logins via VBA, porém não sei nada disso. Gostaria de saber se é necessário saber HTML para fazê-lo, e se alguém conhece alguma boa referência bibliográfica para aprende-lo.
(PS: Eu sei mexer no VBA, mas não nessa parte)

Comment: Do jeito que esta pergunta está, provavelmente será fechada como "muito ampla" ou "baseada em opiniões". Essas sugestões que você quer podem ser encontradas facilmente com uma busca no google. Por exemplo: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/query-table.htm http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scraping-websites-vba.htm

Comment: Olá, boa tarde.
Eu iniciaria a pesquisa direcionando para tutoriais de webcrawler com vba. Você vai precisar entender um pouco de css e html, pois a captura de dados depende de informações baseadas em classes ou ids, mas provavelmente os tutoriais te direcionem a aprender somente o necessário sobre o código-fonte.